# How to set EditorPart header in SharePoint WebParts?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I m trying to set the header for the custom Editor Part section. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EditorPart Class:

```
public class YourCustomEditorPart:System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.EditorPart{
   protected override void CreateChildControls() {
      this.Title = "Editor Part Title Here";
      ...
   }
}
```

Tell the web part that it should use this editor part, instead of the attributed properties.

WebPart Class:

```
public class YourWebPart:System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart, IWebEditable {
...
EditorPartCollection IWebEditable.CreateEditorParts() {
    // control the editorparts
    List<EditorPart> editors = new List<EditorPart>();
    YourCustomEditorPart editorPart = new YourCustomEditorPart();
    editorPart.ID = this.ID + "_editorPart";
    editors.Add(editorPart);
    return new EditorPartCollection(editors);
    }
...
}
```

Check out the below series for details. *(Include download source code)*

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-1-introduction.aspx

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-2-Editor-Parts.aspx

Comment: The answer helped, but unfortunately I cant up vote just yet because I dont have enough points as reputation :(

Comment: I should have thanked you in the previous post itself, better late the never. Thanks MinMin :)
One more question, in the Title section TweetPart Properties the section minimize icon is on the right and is not the same as the inbuilt "+". Is there any way to implement the same?

Comment: Html markup and css for header title is generated from EditorPart class. May be you can override default appearance from this class. I am not sure. If you like to explore more, check this doc. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.editorpart.aspx). And it would be very helpful if you have tools like 'IE Developer toolbar' to analyze css and html from page.

Comment: Thanks once again MinMin. Appreciate time and effort in helping me out.

Comment: @bkk did you ever find out how to manipulate the style of the header? I would prefer to style the header in the same manner as the rest of the categories are.

Comment: @Markus sorry for replying so late, did you get answer for your problem?

Comment: @bkk no sir, I am creating a custom CQWP adding some properties to it but haven't been able to change my custom header to include the "+" and same styling as the other categories listed.